# Rails3 api to retrieve items based on its params using grape

Tags: ruby, api, grape-api

i m working in rails 3

i have a doubt , i have a method to fetch the items based on its tag

like

```
resources "blogs" do
  get '/tag', '/tag/:name' do
    authenticate!
    tag_name = params[:name].to_s || ""
    # query to fetch from items based on its tag associated
  end
end
```

The above one works, now i would like to change the url like

**"apipath/blogs?tag=tag1"**
instead of what i did before as **"apipath/blogs/tag/tag1"**

so i have modified the line

```
  get '/tag', '/tag/:name' do
 ###
  end
```

with

```
get '?tag', '?tag=:name' do
end
```

but this not working ...
Please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

To me this can works :

```
resources "blogs" do
  get '/tag' do
    authenticate!
    tag_name = params[:tag].to_s || ""
    # query to fetch from items based on its tag associated
  end
end
```

You don't need define in your route the params pass by `?` this is not interpret by router.

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditionals in the route with parenthesis:

```
get '/tag(/:name)' do
   # params[:name] will contain the tag name
end
```